# Add nodes to Service Fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

For some reason I can't find how to perform the most basic operation with the service fabric cluster: add more nodes. Please advise. The closest I found is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt125881.aspx, which still seems to be not what I want. All I need is a way to change a number of nodes; I currently have five A1 nodes in my cluster (simplest possible configuration) and I want six.

Answer (score 6):

1) The quickest way to change the number of instances in the VMSS/Node type in your cluster is to submit a change to Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets resource with the change to the "capacity" tag under "sku".

Adding of nodes should not result in any data loss to your stateful services. Deleting a node could, so you will need to gracefully shut down the node first and then delete that instance.

once the new nodes are added, the SF resource balancer will do the load balancing as appropriate.

2) The best way to scale in and out is to set up autoscale rules on VMSS/Nodetype. refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-scale-up-down/ for details.

3) Once the portal experience for VMSS is enabled the experience of adding and/removing nodes will become simple, till then you have to issue manual ARM commands.

4) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt125881.aspx - new node configuration API - you should not be using it for clusters you deploy to Azure. this happens automatically, via the Service fabric extension that gets called once a new VMSS instance shows up.

Comment: _change to the "capacity" tag under "sku"_ - I tried that, doesn't work. New node seems to get provisioned, but does not automatically join the cluster.

Comment: Does your VMSS template have all the necessary Service Fabric bits?  Service Fabric has to be "installed" on top of the VM image, so this needs to be captured in the template.  See here for an example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype-wad/azuredeploy.json

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to redeploy your template. If you don't have a template and simply created your cluster using the portal, go to create a new cluster, and at the point before creation, download the template, as recommended [here.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm/)

Now obviously you don't want to have a whole new cluster, so what you want to do is redeploy the template to the existing cluster in [incremental mode.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-deploy/#incremental-and-complete-deployments) Add a deployment resource to the template, making sure the mode element is Incremental. (I believe deployments actually default to incremental mode, so this may not be necessary... but just in case ;) )

```
{
  "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersionRm')]",
  "name": "[variables('nestedDeploymentNameVnet')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
```

And finally, to change the amount of nodes in the scale set, you simply want to change the number in the capacity element of the scale set.

```
"sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('vmNodeType0Size')]",
    "capacity": "[parameters('node0Capacity')]",
    "tier": "Standard"
```

You can see I have mine as a parameter, so I can easily change the number to whatever I need it to be when I redeploy.

Comment: The goal is to increase the capacity of the cluster without taking it offline or losing the state of actors. From the link you have provided, it seems that the whole scale set will be re-provisioned, not that one VM will be added to it. It is also not clear what will happen to actor state, but most likely it will be gone. I can be mistaken, of course. Please let me know if you have done just that (incremental mode upgrade changing VM scale set capacity), or you just think this is how it should work.

Comment: It explicitly says in my link "does not re-provision resources that exist in the resource group in the same condition defined in the template"

also, here is a link to a template that just changes capacity: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/b8530419842e8e4a3c9c5c77bac78521d8acbdf5/201-vmss-scale-existing/azuredeploy.json

Comment: but you are right, I haven't checked if it maintains state after changing capacity. Give it a go and find out!

Comment: I am not sure what "in the same condition" means. To me, different number of VMs in a scale set is a "different condition" of a scale set - which, therefore, will be re-provisioned. Generally speaking, re-partitioning while maintaining consistency is a hard problem, and I strongly suspect that they "solved" this problem by not allowing to add machines to existing cluster/scale set, thus eliminating the need for re-partitioning. If they did implement it, I would expect this most common use case to have it's own UI representation, or at the very least, it's own powershell command.

Comment: I suspect the reason it doesn't have a UI or powershell way of doing it, is because the point of a scale set is that it will auto-scale. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview/